# How to get each column totals in handsontable?

Tags: handsontable

I'm trying to find out how to create a table that its first row contains the totals of its corresponding column, and then move it to another table in the upper side, I've been able to do the second thing but not the first, in [my customJSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SBRvZ/20/) its located what I have done already, this is the portion of the code I'm trying:

```
  $('#totalOtherConceptC_DataTable').handsontable({
    data: dataOtherConceptCDetails,
    colHeaders: false,
    columns: [{
            type: 'text'
            }, {
            type: 'numeric',
            renderer: function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value){
                        if(row == instance.countRows() - 1){
                            value = Operations.getTotal(1);
                        }

                        Handsontable.NumericRenderer.apply(this, arguments);

                      }
            }]
    });
```

The totals are calculated like this for each column

```
 Operations.getTotal = function(col){
        return dataOtherConceptCDetails.reduce(function(sum, row){
           return sum + row[col]; 
        }, 0);
  };
```

I've been based on [this JSFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/qubkY/) that it works, but when I try to implement it, it doesnt' work at all. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: I've figured out that maybe I can't implement the code based on my example because the first column in my example contains a text, so what could I do?? (I need that column)

Comment: What are you trying to compute on text?  are you trying to add string+string?

Comment: if you enter into the first JSFiddle, you'll see that both tables have in each row, a first column with text, what I want it's that each total in the table below calculate the totals of its column and set it in its Totals (row 0 - columns 1 to last)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem too... The example never worked on a standalone implementation... Here  is the workaround I could come up with: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qubkY/107/)

```
renderer : function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value) {
            if (row == instance.countRows() - 1) {
        value = parseFloat(document.getElementById("cellTotal").value);
    } else {
        setTotalValue(row, value);
    }

Handsontable.renderers.NumericRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
```

Note that I have had to use a hidden placeholder to retain the sum of the column cells. May not be the best approach, but worked for me. Hoping that this would help saving precious time in working around the issue...

Tested with IE 10 and Chrome.

Comment: This was I´ve been looking for, I really appreciate it